# C# MySql как конвертировать mysql таблицу в excel

Tags: c#, mysql, excel

Добрый вечер господа как конвертировать mysql таблицу в excel на C#. Я установил эти ссылки(подключил пакеты):

**Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel**

**Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel**

**Microsoft.Office.Tools.v4.0.Utilities**

вот тут код C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace check_disp
{
public partial class check6 : Form
{
    MySqlConnection myscon = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;initial catalog=test;username=root;password=");

    public check6()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void check6_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter adapt = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM test_tbl", myscon);

            myscon.Open();

            DataSet dset = new DataSet();
            adapt.Fill(dset, "test_tbl");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables["test_tbl"];

            myscon.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for (i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
            {
                DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[j, i];
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = cell.Value;
            }
        }

        xlWorkBook.SaveAs("csharp.net-informations.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);

        MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file c:\\csharp.net-informations.xls");
    }

    private void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Когда запускаю всё норм но после нажатия кнопки button1 выдаёт эту ошибку указывая на эту часть кода где создаётся excel как я понял:

```
xlApp = new Excel.Application();
```

вот что пишется в окне ошибки:

**System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: "Не удалось получить фабрику класса COM для компонента с CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} из-за следующей ошибки: 80040154 Класс не зарегистрирован (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))."**

Я не разобрался с кодом button1_Click, не понял как создать excel файл, нужна помощь!

Comment: Есть подозрение что на машине, где запускаете этот код, Эксель не установлен.

Comment: да excel не установлен, значат причина в этом?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, когда устанавливается Эксель, он регистрирует соответствующий COM компонент, который вы вызываете у себя в коде. Так как  вам написано, что фабрика для компонента не найдена, то есть он не зарегистрирован - я и предположил, что эксель не был установлен.

Comment: Но имейте ввиду, что если у вас задача - получить на выходе эксель файл в формате OpenXML , то для этого не обязательно использовать COM компоненты, так как есть библиотеки, которые могут такой файл сгенерировать самостоятельно, например [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Я пользуюсь OpenOffice по этому не установил MSOffice. тогда установлю и проверю!

Comment: можете в примере показать?

Comment: [тут](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) есть доки и исходники примеров

Comment: Спасибо огромное!